# Lenovo Battery management

Tags: battery

I have a Lenovo laptop computer and recently had to re-install windows 10. when this was done I seem to have lost the battery management option to control when battery charges (i.e. keeping battery in the optimal running zones 20% to 80% I think). I downloaded and install  Lenovo Power management 4 thinking that was it but could not find the options in there. How can I get the one back that was under the battery icon before and had easy access to these options? Thank you

Comment: If the device came with Windows 10, then the software the gave you this ability in the first place was, the Lenovo software.

Comment: I have two different Lenovo laptops running W10, which have somehow finished up with two different Lenovo battery managers, but both are called Energy Manager, and both have the Battery Health option, though the GUIs are very different. I can't easily check on one system, but the other has Version 1.0.0.35 and it's called Conservation Mode, under Settings (I think this was the original program installed with W8 before I uggraded to W10). I don't know what Power Management 4 is, but you should maybe look for Energy Manager on the Lenovo site instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try downloading the [Lenovo Vantage](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/lenovo-vantage/9wzdncrfj4mv) app from the Windows Store. (Note: This link will open the Windows Store app.)

I have an inexpensive Lenovo laptop and I am able to enable "conservation mode", which limits the battery to 60% when plugged in, through the Lenovo Vantage app.